# How to add a gradient tint color to a UISlider in XCode 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, gradient, uislider

I'm working on a design application that has a section for selecting colors by three sliders for RGB.
As we can see in xcode, where we want to select a color by RGB values, the slider tint color is a gradient color that changes when we change the sliders. I want to use this in my application. but I have  no idea about how to do this?

I've found this code in a blog. but didn't work for me.

```
- (void)setGradientToSlider:(UISlider *)Slider WithColors:(NSArray *)Colors{

    UIView * view = (UIView *)[[Slider subviews]objectAtIndex:0];

    UIImageView * maxTrackImageView = (UIImageView *)[[view subviews]objectAtIndex:0];

    CAGradientLayer * maxTrackGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    CGRect rect = maxTrackImageView.frame;
    rect.origin.x = view.frame.origin.x;

    maxTrackGradient.frame = rect;
    maxTrackGradient.colors = Colors;

    [maxTrackGradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
    [maxTrackGradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)];

    [[maxTrackImageView layer] insertSublayer:maxTrackGradient atIndex:0];

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    UIImageView * minTrackImageView = (UIImageView *)[[view subviews]objectAtIndex:1];

    CAGradientLayer * minTrackGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    rect = minTrackImageView.frame;
    rect.size.width = maxTrackImageView.frame.size.width;
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.origin.y = 0;

    minTrackGradient.frame = rect;
    minTrackGradient.colors = Colors;

    [minTrackGradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
    [minTrackGradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)];

    [minTrackImageView.layer insertSublayer:minTrackGradient atIndex:0];

}
```

I would appreciate any helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really effective approach that I've found after a lot of web search. So it's better to share it here as a complete answer. The following code is a `Swift Class` That you can use to create and use gradients as `UIView` or `UIImage`.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Gradient: UIView{
    // Gradient Color Array
    private var Colors: [UIColor] = []

    // Start And End Points Of Linear Gradient
    private var SP: CGPoint = CGPoint.zeroPoint
    private var EP: CGPoint = CGPoint.zeroPoint

    // Start And End Center Of Radial Gradient
    private var SC: CGPoint = CGPoint.zeroPoint
    private var EC: CGPoint = CGPoint.zeroPoint

    // Start And End Radius Of Radial Gradient
    private var SR: CGFloat = 0.0
    private var ER: CGFloat = 0.0

    // Flag To Specify If The Gradient Is Radial Or Linear
    private var flag: Bool = false

    // Some Overrided Init Methods
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    // Draw Rect Method To Draw The Graphics On The Context
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Get Context
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // Get Color Space
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        // Create Arrays To Convert The UIColor to CG Color
        var colorComponent: [CGColor] = []
        var colorLocations: [CGFloat] = []
        var i: CGFloat = 0.0

        // Add Colors Into The Color Components And Use An Index Variable For Their Location In The Array [The Location Is From 0.0 To 1.0]
        for color in Colors {
            colorComponent.append(color.CGColor)
            colorLocations.append(i)
            i += CGFloat(1.0) / CGFloat(self.Colors.count - 1)
        }

        // Create The Gradient With The Colors And Locations
        let gradient: CGGradientRef = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colorComponent, colorLocations)

        // Create The Suitable Gradient Based On Desired Type
        if flag {
            CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, SC, SR, EC, ER, 0)
        } else {
            CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, SP, EP, 0)
        }
    }

    // Get The Input Data For Linear Gradient
    func CreateLinearGradient(startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint, colors: UIColor...) {
        self.Colors = colors
        self.SP = startPoint
        self.EP = endPoint
        self.flag = false
    }

    // Get The Input Data For Radial Gradient
    func CreateRadialGradient(startCenter: CGPoint, startRadius: CGFloat, endCenter: CGPoint, endRadius: CGFloat, colors: UIColor...) {
        self.Colors = colors
        self.SC = startCenter
        self.EC = endCenter
        self.SR = startRadius
        self.ER = endRadius
        self.flag = true
    }

    // Function To Convert Gradient To UIImage And Return It
    func getImage() -> UIImage {
        // Begin Image Context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size)

        // Draw The Gradient
        self.drawRect(self.frame)

        // Get Image From The Current Context
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        // End Image Context
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        // Return The Result Gradient As UIImage
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide usage explanation of  this code?

Answer (score 13):

While it didnt give me the desired results here is a down and dirty Swift version of the answer above for those that want to try it.

```
func setSlider(slider:UISlider) {

    let tgl = CAGradientLayer()
    let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, slider.frame.size.width, 5)
    tgl.frame = frame
    tgl.colors = [UIColor.blueColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor, UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor, UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor, UIColor.redColor().CGColor]
    tgl.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
    tgl.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tgl.frame.size, tgl.opaque, 0.0);
    tgl.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    image.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero)

    slider.setMinimumTrackImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    //slider.setMaximumTrackImage(image, forState: .Normal)

}
```

**UPDATE for Swift 4.0**

```
func setSlider(slider:UISlider) {
    let tgl = CAGradientLayer()
    let frame = CGRect.init(x:0, y:0, width:slider.frame.size.width, height:5)
    tgl.frame = frame
    tgl.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.orange.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    tgl.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x:0.0, y:0.5)
    tgl.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x:1.0, y:0.5)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tgl.frame.size, tgl.isOpaque, 0.0);
    tgl.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)

        slider.setMinimumTrackImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: But i have a swift version that gives the desired results. In case that you may wanna use it, I will share it here

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian it works ... just not as I wanted it to. The images scale when you slide, so for example if I had red and blue only, I'd like the red to show up to 50% of the slide then the other 50% shows the blue. But this was the red and blue are always visible just scaled down to fit content size.

Comment: Take A Look At My Answer. You Should Manipulate Locations For Your Problem. And You Have To Refresh The Gradient Whenever  Th View Changes

Comment: this should be the accepted solution! thanks @DogCoffee

Comment: gradient is added but control becomes broken - no line caps, line gains y offset and etc

Comment: This is so close, except ```image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)``` returns a UIImage, but that isn't getting assigned to a variable. if you assign the result of that call to a variable, and then pass that in to setMinTrackImage, it works great

Answer (score 6):

Here is possible solution:

**Usage:**

```
//array of CGColor objects, color1 and color2 are UIColor objects 
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)color1.CGColor, (id)color2.CGColor, nil];
//your UISlider
[slider setGradientBackgroundWithColors:colors];
```

**Implementation:**

Create category on `UISlider`:

```
- (void)setGradientBackgroundWithColors:(NSArray *)colors
{
    CAGradientLayer *trackGradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height = 5.0; //set the height of slider
    trackGradientLayer.frame = frame;
    trackGradientLayer.colors = colors;
    //setting gradient as horizontal
    trackGradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
    trackGradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);

    UIImage *trackImage = [[UIImage imageFromLayer:trackGradientLayer] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [self setMinimumTrackImage:trackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setMaximumTrackImage:trackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Where `colors` is array of CGColor.

I have also created a category on `UIImage` which creates image from layer as you need an `UIImage` for setting gradient on slider.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, layer.opaque, 0.0);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

Comment: excellent! thanks although to be 100% correct I would use frame = [self trackRectForBounds:self.bounds]; so it will work fine even with maximum and minimum images

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3 and to prevent the slider from scaling the Min image, apply this when setting the its image. Recalculating the slider's left side is not necessary. Only recalc if you can changing the color of the gradient. The Max image does not seem to scale, but you should probably apply the same setting for consistency. There is a slight difference on the Max image when not applying its insets.

```
slider.setMinimumTrackImage(image?.resizableImage(withCapInsets:.zero), for: .normal)
```

For some reason it only works properly when resizableImage(withCapInsets:.zero) is all done at the same time.  Running that part separate does not allow the image to work and gets scaled.

Here is the entire routine in Swift 3:

```
func setSlider(slider:UISlider) {
    let tgl = CAGradientLayer()
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: slider.bounds.width, height: 5.0 )
    tgl.frame = frame
    tgl.colors = [ UIColor.yellow.cgColor,UIColor.black.cgColor]
    tgl.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:  1.0)
    tgl.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:  1.0)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tgl.frame.size, false, 0.0)
    tgl.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    slider.setMaximumTrackImage(image?.resizableImage(withCapInsets:.zero),  for: .normal)
    slider.setMinimumTrackImage(image?.resizableImage(withCapInsets:.zero),  for: .normal)
}
```